# SQL: Finding students who fulfill a course prerequsite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have these two tables: 
prerequisite: (cid, pre-cid)
(record: sid, cid, qtr , year, grade).

I have to find the students who fulfill the prerequisites for a certain class using only NOT IN. My current query is:

```
select distinct sid
from record
where sid not in (
        select s.sid
        from record s,
            prerequisite p
        where p.cid = "CSE132X"
            and s.cid <> p.precid
            and s.grade < 2
        );
```

However, my query returns students who have taken any prerequisite, not all the prerequisites. I'm having trouble figuring out how to make it so that it checks for all the prerequisites of the course.

Comment: Sample data along with expected result set will help clarify what you are actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct r.sid
from record r
where r.sid not in (
    select r.sid
    from prerequisite c
    where c.cid = "CSE132X" and 
    c.pre-cid not in (
          select r2.cid
          from record r2
          where r2.sid = r.sid
    )
);
```

Comment: Yes, I knew I needed two nested queries but was having a very hard time with what to put in each nested query. I understand now I was supposed to do a pre-cid not in nested query. Thank you!

Comment: @L.S. The logic `X = not not X` can be expressed in English as "has taken all prerequisites = there are no prerequisites that are not taken".

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

`select distinct sid from record y where grade>=2 and not exists( select * from prerequisite where cid='CSE132X' and precid not in (select cid from record x where x.sid=y.sid) );`

Comment: Thank you, I was able to turn this into a query using only NOT IN and produce the correct output:

    select distinct y.sid from record y where y.grade >= 2 and y.sid not in 
    (select s.sid from record s, prerequisite p where p.cid = "CSE132X" 
    and p.precid not in (select x.cid from record x where x.sid = y.sid));